# Anaconda3 PATH variable issue on Windows 10

Tags: qt, installation, anaconda, spyder, path-variables

I installed Anaconda3 in the default directory : C:\Users\MyUserName

When I am launching Spyder or Anaconda Navigator, `Qt` is not founded :

[image: Qt_not_founded]

Furthermore, `conda` is not recognized by default in the Anaconda Prompt.

[image: conda_not_founded]

However,`conda` is recognized if I specify the directory.

[image: conda_founded_2]

It all seems like a PATH variable issue. The thing is, I have created a list of PATH variables in the [windows variable manager](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) (My PC -> Properties -> Advanced ...) . I tried a few paths, but it still doesn't work.

[image: path_variables]

Am I missing a PATH variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please also add the following paths:

**C:\Users...\Anaconda3\bin**

**C:\Users...\Anaconda3\condabin**

and check if you gain access to the conda command?

Comment: No it didn't work, but I founded the solution.Thanks anyway

Comment: @dreab As mentionned : The problem was the 'è' (or the special character to be more generic) in my user name.

I uninstalled Anaconda3, removed all PATH variables and reinstalled it with admin privileges on C:\ProgramData. No special character. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Anaconda3, removed all PATH variables related to Anaconda, and reinstalled it with admin privileges on C:\ProgramData.

The problem was the 'è' character in my user name.